# Force action to respond to turbo_stream

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails 7.1 app, I'm implementing SSO using the [Ruby SAML](https://github.com/SAML-Toolkits/ruby-saml).
Based on the sample app, I have created the simple controller below

```rb
class SamlController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_settings, only: [:sso, :acs, :metadata]
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [:acs, :logout]

  def sso
    request = OneLogin::RubySaml::Authrequest.new
    redirect_to request.create(@settings), allow_other_host: true
  end

  def acs
    response = OneLogin::RubySaml::Response.new(params[:SAMLResponse], settings: @settings)
    if response.is_valid?
      session[:nameid] = response.nameid
      respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to dashboard_path }
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        flash.now[:alert] = "error"
        format.turbo_stream { render :flash }
      end
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

When the response is not valid, I want to use a `turbo stream` response to display feedback to the user without fully rendering the page.

Since the `acs` action is called by the identity provider, it responds to `html` and I get a `ActionController::UnknownFormat in SamlController#acs` error.

I have tried to change the `else` branch as follows

```
render turbo_stream: 'flash'
```

But, instead of rendering the feedback, it downloads a file with the partial source code.

The same happens if, at the beginning of the action, I add

```
request.format = "turbo_stream"
```

At the controller level, is there a way to force to respond to `turbo_stream`?